# Html <object> forces repaint on scroll in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll, repaint

I have multiple html  tags on my page that call flash (players/ads... etc). Adding onscroll animation to my page (all native JS) is jittery because all the flash objets are repainting on scroll. I can see that those objects are repainting by enabling "Show potential scroll bottlenecks" in Developer tools in Chrome. Is there anything I can do to force these flash objects to NOT repaint on scroll?

Thanks in advance

Zaid

Comment: AFAIK no, you can't... This behavior is 1) native from FlashPlayer and 2) necessary, since once you scroll the page, the flash object changes its position and need to redraws itself.

Comment: Solution: don't use flash. Go with pure JavaScript, HTML and CSS. The nice thing about doing that is that ads will be shown on mobile devices that don't support flash. As for players: look in to HTML 5 Video.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I will try to use HTML5 video and see how that goes